# c# vmware sdk : get list of all guest vm hosted on hostsystem?

Tags: c#, vmware

Say I got some vms (linuxtestguest, ubunuttestguest...) that are hosted on a virtual server named test.

How do you get the list of all VMs hosted on "test" ?

I can list all the hosts ("test" in my case) by following rootFolder (folder) -> childentity (datacenter) -> hostFolder(Folder) -> childentity (ComputerResource) -> host(HostSystem)

I can list all available Vms by following rootFolder (folder) -> childentity (datacenter) -> vmFolder(Folder) -> childentity (VirtualMachine)

But how do I link the two ? Being given an host how do i get all the vms attached to it ? (and if possible the other way around)

This looks very basic to me (this is the first practical use of SDK I can think of) but I don't find any doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the VM information once you are connected to your vCenter via C# code, below is the sample code to start with, following code connects to your vCenter server and get all the VM's info as list and using using this list you can traverse to all the properties of VM you want to access.

```
//Include VMware C# sdk VMware.VIM dll as reference in your project
//try to invoke client connection
VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl client = new VimClientImpl();
client.Connect(@"VMware_Server_IP/sdk");
// Login using username/password credentials
UserSession session = client.Login("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

//Getting all the virtual machine and the datastore info from the VCenter
NameValueCollection filter = new NameValueCollection();
IList vmList = client.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, filter, null);`
```

You can search for *FindEntityViews* as it accepts different parameter based on need, here I have used **"VirtualMachine"** parameter to get the VM's info, you can use **"Datastore"** to get all the datastore info and likewise. Hope it helps to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant. But you have a property called "vm" on a host that lists the vms on this host.

By the way, I'm not sure if you're familiar with it but you can always use the **mob (managed object browser)** of a virtual center. You can do it by browsing to this url:

```
https://<vcenter-ip>/mob
```

After entering your credentials, you will get to an html browser of the virtual managed object. Start from "content" and from there you can travel to rootFolder->childEntitity and so on. When you'll get to host(HostSystem) you'll see at the end of the properties table the property "vm" I mentioned. Good luck :)